# fill in missing dates, from weekly to daily using python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe and I would like to make weekly data just repeat for daily until the next week

Input

```
Week          Netflix: (Worldwide)
2012-12-02    50
2012-12-09    51
```

Output

```
Week        Netflix: (Worldwide)
2012-12-02  50
2012-12-03  50
2012-12-04  50
2012-12-05  50
2012-12-06  50
2012-12-07  50
2012-12-08  50
2012-12-09  51
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
In [129]: df.set_index('Week').resample('1D').ffill().reset_index()
Out[129]:
        Week  Netflix: (Worldwide)
0 2012-12-02                    50
1 2012-12-03                    50
2 2012-12-04                    50
3 2012-12-05                    50
4 2012-12-06                    50
5 2012-12-07                    50
6 2012-12-08                    50
7 2012-12-09                    51
```

or alternative solution from [@Wen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47500610/fill-in-missing-dates-from-weekly-to-daily-using-python-pandas/47500903?noredirect=1#comment81957867_47500903):

```
In [147]: df.set_index('Week').asfreq('D').ffill().reset_index()
Out[147]:
        Week  Netflix: (Worldwide)
0 2012-12-02                  50.0
1 2012-12-03                  50.0
2 2012-12-04                  50.0
3 2012-12-05                  50.0
4 2012-12-06                  50.0
5 2012-12-07                  50.0
6 2012-12-08                  50.0
7 2012-12-09                  51.0
```

Comment: `df.set_index('Week').asfreq('D').ffill()` or we can using `asfreq`

Comment: @Wen, yeah, nice idea - post it as an answer, please

Comment: man add it to yours let us make this site straightforward to the answer：-）

Comment: @Wen, OK, added to mine  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( [ ['2012-12-02', 50], ['2012-12-09', 51]], columns=['Week', 'Netflix: (Worldwide)'])
df['Week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Week'])

min_date = df['Week'].min()
max_date = df['Week'].max()

idx = pd.date_range(min_date, max_date)
df = df.set_index('Week')
df = df.reindex(idx)
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.rename(columns={'index':'Week'}, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output -

```
   Week                Netflix: (Worldwide)
0 2012-12-02                  50.0
1 2012-12-03                  50.0
2 2012-12-04                  50.0
3 2012-12-05                  50.0
4 2012-12-06                  50.0
5 2012-12-07                  50.0
6 2012-12-08                  50.0
7 2012-12-09                  51.0
```

Comment: @---> 10 df = df.reset_index(), brings an error code. cannot insert level_0, already exists

Comment: @ReeseFitzmaurice Pandas tries to insert a column 'index' or 'level_0'. If either/both(??) of them are already taken, then it throws the error.

Fortunately, there's a "drop" option. Updated Answer. Please check